# Storage large amout of small data inside Android app

Tags: java, android, database, tabs, storage

I'm developing app which works with beacons. I need to keep all 
Addresses and time of all occurations (It will be from 0 to about 250K occurations). Then I will count number of occurations in time interval all this beacons. I'm looking for idea how to do that or what will be best way ? Summarizing I need to storage about 250k names + time occurations with easy acces to use it later to count this occurations per beacon. Should I just use Tab ? or maybe database?

P.S sorry for weak and chaotic language

Comment: if no need for sql, than maybe [snappydb](https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB)?

Comment: Theoretically, I have no restrictions about this. Just if it works faster then better + size of this app can't be to big

Comment: but I don't hear before about this

Comment: well it's fast as a thunder, but i have no idea how much space it will take

Comment: I saw benchmark and reading data by snappy is Slower than by using Realm. I need to admit that quite important is easy way to implement all this :)

Comment: if you dont care that realm adds couple of MB to the final apk, then you can use it...

Comment: that's not good either

Comment: @pskink Snappy sounds good but tell me Can I use Select Sql queries?

Comment: no, it is nosql db, but read this: https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB#keys-search

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite database for these type of storage. You can use any wrapper of SQL ORMlite , GreenDAO etc for your ease.

Answer (score 0):

I have work with beacons too and I had to store a large amount of data.
A simple implementation of SQLite solved the purpose.

I recommend you this tutorial :
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/